# Multiple bags Exception / Buscando várias coleções com JPA

Tags: java, query, jpa, exceção

Estou com um problema com JPA na hora de fazer uma consulta.

Quero consultar a Entidade A que possui uma `List` de Entidade B e `List` de Entidade C (quero consultar a Entidade A trazendo os relacionamentos com as Entidades B e C em uma mesma `query`).

Quando tento executar essa query a exceção de *multiple bags* é lançada.

Tem alguma forma de fazer essa consulta sem ter que usar `@IndexColumn`, `Fetch.EAGER` ou alterar `List` para `Set`? (Soluções que encontrei na internet)

OBS: não coloquei o código aqui pois só quero saber se existe uma outra alternativa além dessas que citei anteriormente.

Comment: Já resolvi, e obrigado à quem votou negativo ;)

Answer (score 0):

A causa mais comum para este erro é quando você tenta fazer 2 (ou mais) `JOIN`s usando `FETCH`, sendo que cada um destes `JOIN`s é por meio de uma `List`.

Vamos a um exemplo. Dada as (pseudo) entidades:

```
@Entity
class Entidade1 {
    private List<Entidade2> entidades2;
}

@Entity
class Entidade2 {
    private List<Entidade3> entidades3;
}
```

O seguinte JPQL irá reproduzir o problema:

```
SELECT e1 FROM Entidade1 e1
JOIN FETCH e1.entidades2 e2
JOIN FETCH e2.entidades3 e3
```

A solução mais comum é esta: alterar de `List` para `Set` o mapeamento de `entidades2` e `entidades3`. A solução com `EAGER` eu nem consideraria, tamanha as consequência que ela pode trazer para a aplicação.

Ou, se possível, evite usar um `JOIN FETCH` a partir de outro. Até onde sei, apenas o Hibernate suporta *alias* em `JOIN FETCH`, permitindo este tipo de situação e erro.

Assim, a **solução que recomendo** é considerar o uso de um `VO`, trazendo apenas o que precisa das 3 entidades:

```
SELECT new br.com.EntidadeVO(e1.id, e1.nome, e2.id, e3.nome) FROM Entidade1 e1
JOIN e1.entidades2 e2
JOIN e2.entidades3 e3
```